# Setting permissions of uploaded file to allow reading in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, file, permissions

I have an ASP.NET web application in which I am trying to open a text file located within a subdirectory of my webroot. The text file was uploaded through the same web application using SAFileUp. I am using the FileInfo object as such to read the text file ...

```
Response.TransmitFile(fileInfo.FullName)
```

The puzzling thing is I get an exception thrown when I execute this line of code.

```
Access to the path 'C:\webroot\xxxx\uploads\filename.txt' is denied
```

I have given the `uploads` folder, where the text file was uploaded, `read/write/execute` permissions to both the `IUSR` and `IIS_IUSRS` account and the permissions have inherited to the sub folders below. The interesting thing is the actual text document I am trying to load has NO permissions set for `IIS_IUSRS` while `IUSR` does have read/write/execute. As soon as I add the "read" permission to `IIS_IUSRS` I am able to read the file.

What confuses me is I would have thought the file would have inherited the permissions from the parent folders, but apparently not. How do I set the permissions of the uploaded file during the upload process so I can open it later for reading?

Comment: Have you checked if the file is read only

Comment: @Swaff - Yes, I did. It was not read-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well .. I found the answer. Basically, the upload component SAFileUp, uses the "Temp" directory where the uploaded file is cached to set the permissions of the uploaded file. In my case this directory was `C:\Windows\temp`. All I did was give the account `IIS_IUSRS` READ access to the `C:\Windows\temp` directory and I was able to access the uploaded file without issue.

Here is an article on SoftArtisans's website that clued me in and helped me find the directory the uploaded file was cached to.

http://support.softartisans.com/kbview_776.aspx